# Can multiple build configs share one config transformation?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, continuous-integration, web-config-transform, slowcheetah

I'm using SlowCheetah for XML transforming a bunch of config files in a project.

However, this same solution is part of a load balanced setup, where some config values differ between the different servers (two, in this case).

I have the following build configs

- Debug
- Release
- Release.Test
- Release.Prod1
- Release.Prod2

Almost everything in Release.Prod1 and Release.Prod2 is identical, except for some values in one of the config files. Is there any way I can have a file like `Something.Release.Prod.Config` to be used on both of these build configs instead of having two identical files (`Something.Release.Prod1.Config` and `Something.Release.Prod2.Config`)?

...and to elaborate: In this case I am deploying to *two* environments, so one duplicated file is not really a huge crisis. What if you have ten or a hundred servers? I see no reason why a setup with a CI-server (Specifically TeamCity in this case) should not be able to do this, even though I suppose more customized setups are common in such environments.

How is this usually handled?

I suppose I can do some magic copying of files back and forth as a build step before the actual transformation happens, but this seems like a messy and overly complicated solution.

Comment: something we are trying to figure out here as well... T4 templates are being mooted but I don't particularly like them. I prefer the config transformation but would like to extend it beyond Debug & Release versions.. Just like you are trying to figure out

Comment: Extending beyond debug and release is easy, that's just about adding more build configs from the Build => Build Configurations menu. Making some of them share one file, however...

Answer (score 1):

The configuration transformations are handled by the $(Configuration) variable in the TransformsFiles.targets file.

```
 <TransformXml Source="@(_FilesToTransformNotAppConfig->'%(FullPath)')"
                  Transform="%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)"
                  Destination="@(_FilesToTransformNotAppConfig->'$(OutDir)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
                  Condition=" Exists('%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)') " />
```

Here, you can change $(Configuration) to be any other value, like "Environment". Then just set the "Environment" variable in your MSBuild args -

```
/p:Environment=Prod
```

This should allow you to keep your build settings and do your transforms independently.